# Adding a Swipe Transition to Ionic Tab Navigation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm making a Cordova application with the Ionic framework, specifically the tab-navigation template. I was looking up how to add the ability to swipe between each tab and came across [this example][1]. After reading I added the following to my controller.

```
.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope, $ionicTabsDelegate) {

    $scope.goForward = function () {
        var selected = $ionicTabsDelegate.selectedIndex();
        if (selected != -1) {
            $ionicTabsDelegate.select(selected + 1);
        }
    }

    $scope.goBack = function () {
        var selected = $ionicTabsDelegate.selectedIndex();
        if (selected != -1 && selected != 0) {
            $ionicTabsDelegate.select(selected - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

It works, but I have one complaint. Swiping changes the view but there is not an animation/transition going from one view to another. Is there a way to add some sort of animation/transition?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the swiping. You can apply classes on your tabs to enable animations, something like this would work: `<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-positive fade-in-not-out">`

Comment: I still will need the Javascript I currently have correct? The classes are for the animations in CSS? @devqon

Comment: Yes that is correct